# Storing and retrieving files stored separately from codebase coldfusion

Tags: file-upload, coldfusion, download

We currently have a site running cold fusion 11. In an effort to improve some aspects of security we would like to store all files uploaded by our users on a server separate from our codebase and DB servers.

I'm pretty much starting from scratch here as I wasn't able to find much in my searches so far. What's the best practice for doing this and what cold fusion functions would work for storing and retrieving files from an external source?

Comment: Assuming you have the appropriate permissions in place, cffile should work.  The documentation says to use the full pathname for the file attribute.  In this case, that path would be a network path, starting with \\.

Answer (score 4):

I could use some more information to be more helpful. But let's say you have a separate server that stores all your user files on a Windows network. I would use CFContent to serve those files with the file being retrieved over a UNC path.

I'd recommend reading this blog entry of mine on [Securely Serving Files via CFContent](http://christierney.com/2009/08/12/securely-serving-files-via-cfcontent/). Wil, also from [CF Webtools](http://www.cfwebtools.com), posts one here: [Serving File Downloads with ColdFusion](http://www.trunkful.com/index.cfm/2010/8/4/Serving-File-Downloads-with-ColdFusion)

Comment: I wish I could be more specific but due to the nature of the site I'm a bit limited on what I'm allowed to post. Thanks for the quick response if I had enough reputation I'd up-vote, those links are very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

We had a similar issue when we migrated to a Unix platform. Our solution was to mount a file server to the webserver. It's accessed programmatically by ColdFusion as if it's on the same server, but it's inaccessible from the web root (browser). It's worked very smoothly for us.